# Bounce rate from the Alexa API

Tags: amazon-web-services, alexa-internet

Does the Alexa API give a way to query Bounce Rates? There seems to be no ResponseGroup that returns this information. I've tried all the ResponseGroups and Actions mentioned in the documentation [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AlexaWebInfoService/latest/).

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to get highly accurate data via their API, but the alternative is to use SimilarWeb API for engagement data such as:

- Average Page Views
- Average number of page views per visitor
- Average Time On Site
- Bounce Rate

You can read more about the [Engagement API](https://developer.similarweb.com/engagement_api) in this link: https://developer.similarweb.com/engagement_api

Comment: Thanks. Do you mean "there is no way to get accurate data" or "there is no way to get accurate bounce rate data" from Alexa?